# Mp4parser: how to get matrix values for further use?

Tags: java, android, mp4parser

I want to get the double values out of the mp4parser Matrix, for use in some formulas. Is there any method/utility for this? I am using the last version for gradle, i.e. 1.1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. If there's a simpler one, please post it.
If `a` is a mp4parser Matrix, then here is how to get in `m` the double values:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(36);
a.getContent(bb);
bb.position(0);
double [] m = {
    IsoTypeReader.readFixedPoint1616(bb),
    IsoTypeReader.readFixedPoint1616(bb),
    IsoTypeReader.readFixedPoint0230(bb),
    IsoTypeReader.readFixedPoint1616(bb),
    IsoTypeReader.readFixedPoint1616(bb),
    IsoTypeReader.readFixedPoint0230(bb),
    IsoTypeReader.readFixedPoint1616(bb),
    IsoTypeReader.readFixedPoint1616(bb),
    IsoTypeReader.readFixedPoint0230(bb)};
```